# Entity Framework Core 3 Preview 7 - Include required for properties used in Where

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

Previously this would work:

```
var query = _context.Favourites
                    .Where(o => o.User.UserId == user.UserId);
```

Now I needed to include 'Include' for the 'User' object

```
var query = _context.Favourites
                    .Include(o => o.User)
                    .Where(o => o.User.UserId == user.UserId);
```

Is that right?  Has this changed in `Entity Framework Core 3 Preview 7`?

If I do not include it I get an unfriendly exception.

Comment: Don't create assumptions based on preview software functionality. Many things in preview versions might not work as expected. Preview versions are just to … well, give you the "feeling" of what they are doing. Don't use them in production code - use the latest stable 2.x and wait for 3.0 release (or at least release candidate). `Include` wasn't needed for proper predicated functioning in 2.x, and won't be needed in 3.0 either (when stabilized).

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Core allows you to use the navigation properties in your model to load related entities. There are three common O/RM patterns used to load related data.

**Eager loading** means that the related data is loaded from the database as part of the initial query.

**Explicit loading** means that the related data is explicitly loaded from the database at a later time.

**Lazy loading** means that the related data is transparently loaded from the database when the navigation property is accessed.

**When to use eager loading**

- In "one side" of one-to-many relations that you sure are used every
  where with main entity. like User property of a Favourite. Category
  property of a Product.
- Generally When relations are not too much and
  eager loading will be good practice to reduce further queries on
  server.

**When to use lazy loading**

- Almost on every "collection side" of one-to-many relations. like
  Favourites of User or Products of a Category.
- You exactly know that you will not need a property instantly.

**Note**: there may be disposal problem with lazy loading.

For more details on Loading Related Data in EF Core , you could refer to [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)